# Vagrant - shell provisioner cannot set PATH variable

Tags: bash, environment-variables, vagrant

I want to setup Ubuntu 18.04 VM with installed go. I have the following shell provisioner script:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/go/go1.15.5.linux-amd64.tar.gz
sudo tar -xzvf go1.15.5.linux-amd64.tar.gz
sudo mv /home/vagrant/go /usr/local

echo "export GOROOT=/usr/local/go" >> /home/vagrant/.bashrc
echo "export PATH=$GOROOT/bin:$PATH" >> /home/vagrant/.bashrc
source /home/vagrant/.bashrc

go version
```

But provisioning still fails with non-zero exit code. When I log into vagrant user account I have set `GOROOT`, but `PATH` does not contain `/usr/local/go`.

```
vagrant@vm:~$ echo $PATH
/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin

vagrant@vm:~$ echo $GOROOT
/usr/local/go

vagrant@vm:~$ go

Command 'go' not found, but can be installed with:

snap install go         # version 1.15.6, or
apt  install golang-go
apt  install gccgo-go

See 'snap info go' for additional versions.
```

Downloading go is correct, I have all files under `/usr/local/go`.

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem stems from using double-quotes, which allow interpolation of variables. When your shell script executed this line:

```
echo "export PATH=$GOROOT/bin:$PATH" >> /home/vagrant/.bashrc
```

The value of GOROOT *in that executing shell environment* was empty, so the effect of that command was:

```
echo "export PATH=/bin:$PATH" >> /home/vagrant/.bashrc
```

... which is exactly what you saw with:

> vagrant@vm:~$ echo $PATH

> /bin:...

```
^ here.
```

You want that code to be placed verbatim in the file, so use single quotes:

```
echo 'export GOROOT=/usr/local/go' >> /home/vagrant/.bashrc
echo 'export PATH=$GOROOT/bin:$PATH' >> /home/vagrant/.bashrc
```